# Change x- and y-numbering in imshow

Tags: python, plot, imshow

I would like to plot a function of two variables in python. Similar to [this article](https://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-plot-two-variable-functions-with.html), we can obtain an output like

[image]

using this code:

```
from numpy import exp,arange
from pylab import meshgrid,cm,imshow,contour,clabel,colorbar,axis,title,show
from matplotlib import pyplot

# the function that I'm going to plot
def z_func(x,y):
 return (1-(x**2+y**3))*exp(-(x**2+y**2)/2)

x = arange(-3.0,3.0,0.1)
y = arange(-3.0,3.0,0.1)
z = [[0] * y.__len__() for i in range(x.__len__())]
for i in range(0, x.__len__()):
    for j in range(0, y.__len__()):
        z[j][i] = z_func(x[i], y[j])
   
im = imshow(z,cmap=cm.RdBu, extent = [-3, 3, -3, 3], interpolation = "none", origin='lower') # drawing the function
# adding the Contour lines with labels
cset = contour(z,arange(-1,1.5,0.2),linewidths=2,cmap=cm.Set2)
clabel(cset,inline=True,fmt='%1.1f',fontsize=10)
colorbar(im) # adding the colobar on the right
# latex fashion title
title('$z=(1-x^2+y^3) e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$')
show()
```

As you can see, the x- and y-labels go from 0 to 59 (which is the count of elements in `x` and `y`). How can I correct these values such that they range from -3 to 3?

A minor sub-question: Why do I need to "transpose" in `z[j][i] = z_func(x[i], y[j])`? Does Python treat the first dimension as "column" and the second as "row"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to plot both the z-function and the countour plots. You need to add the "*extent*" parameter to [matplotlib.pyplot.countour](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) plot too.

```
cset = contour(z, arange(-1,1.5,0.2), 
               extent = [-3, 3, -3, 3], 
               linewidths = 2, 
               cmap = cm.Set2)
```